# Get Request URI PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am struck in getting the URI in my wordpress application and lack of PHP knowledge is making my progress slow.
I have this URL

```
http://abc.com/my-blog/abc/cde
```

i need to create a URL something like

```
http://abc.com/my-blog/added-value/abc/cde
```

where  `http://abc.com/my-blog` is the URL of my wordpress blog which i can easily get using following method

```
home_url()
```

i can use PHP `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` to get request URI which will come up as

```
/my-blog/abc/cde
```

and than i have no direct way to add value as per my requirement

is there any way to achieve this easily in PHP or Wordpress where i can get following information

1. Home URL
2. Rest part of the URL

so that in end i can do following

```
Home-URL+ custom-value+Rest part of the URL
```

My point of Confusion

1. On my local set up `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` is giving me `/my-blog/abc/cde`, where `/my-blog` is installation directory of wordpress and i can easily skip first level.
2. On production server its not same as `/my-blog` will not be part of the URL.

Comment: Will the `/my-blog/` always be `/my-blog/` ?

Comment: Using `explode()` and some simple array manipulation. Where are you stuck?

Comment: @F4r-20:no my blog will not be same,its local wordpress setup so `home_url()` is giving this, but on the production it will give me `www.mysite.com`

Comment: @MadaraUchiha:well i was not struck and agree about `explode()`, i was not sure and of impression that there might be a simple way to do this.

Comment: What is `custom-value`?  If you are using wordpress there is likely a much better way to handle this.  Could you elaborate on what you are doing?  Are you trying to access a category, custom post type, tag, archive etc?

Comment: You can use `explode()` to split up the URL, then do all your manipulations before you can `implode()` it back into a string.

Comment: @Jrod:well i am trying to create a custom URL and i have a URL-Rewrting rule based on the generated URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very briefly:

```
<?php

$url = "http://abc.com/my-blog/abc/cde";

$parts = parse_url($url);

$path = explode("/", $parts["path"]);
array_splice($path, 2, 0, array("added-part")); //This line does the magic!

echo $parts["scheme"] . "://" . $parts["host"] . implode("/",$path);
```

Comment: i have a small confusion, as i described `my-blog` is due to wordpress installation and it will not be there in production so URL will come up as `http://abc.com/abc/cde/any length`

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi: In that case, instead of `2` on `array_splice`, use `1`. That parameter determines the position of the inserted element :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so if `$addition` is the bit you want in the middle and `$uri` is what you obtain from `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` then this..

```
$addition = "MIDDLEBIT/";
$uri = "/my-blog/abc/cde";

$parts = explode("/",$uri);
$homeurl = $parts[1]."/";
for($i=2;$i<count($parts);$i++){
    $resturl .= $parts[$i]."/";
}
echo $homeurl . $addition . $resturl;
```

Should print:

> my-blog/MIDDLEBIT/abc/cde/

Comment: Cool, but the loop is redundant.

Comment: Check my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use explode or some other sting function.  Some examples below:

```
  $urlBits = explode($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);

  //blog address
  $blogAddress = $urlBits[0];

  //abc
  $secondPartOfUri = $urlBits[1];

  //cde
  $thirdPartOfUri = $urlBits[2];

  //all of uri except your blog address
  $uri = str_replace("/my-blog/", "", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a reliable way to get current url in PHP .

```php
    public static function getCurrentUrl($withQuery = true)
    {
        $protocol = stripos($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'], 'https') === false ? 'http' : 'https';
        $uri = $protocol . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

        return $withQuery ? $uri : str_replace('?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], '', $uri);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can store the home url in a variable, using wordpress, using [get_home_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_home_url)

```
$home_url = get_home_url();

$custom_value = '/SOME_VALUE';

$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$new_url = $home_url . $custom_value . $uri;
```